# scraping html tables without an obvious pagination class using R and Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from a site ([thenumbers.com](https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/domestic/all-movies/cumulative/all-time)) where the data breaks across many webpages. The format of the sequential webpages looks like this (below are just the first three):

```
url0 <- "https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/domestic/all-movies/cumulative/all-time"
url1 <- "https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/domestic/all-movies/cumulative/all-time/101"
url2 <- "https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/domestic/all-movies/cumulative/all-time/201"
```

To scrape the first sequential url (url0) into a df, this code returns the correct output.

```
library(rvest)

webpage <- read_html("https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/domestic/all-movies/cumulative/all-time")

tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

head(tbls)

tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[1] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

df <- tbls_ls[[1]]
```

where the output looks like:

```
> head(df)
  Rank Released                                Movie DomesticBox Office
1    1     2015 Star Wars Ep. VII: The Force Awakens       $936,662,225
2    2     2009                               Avatar       $760,507,625
3    3     2018                        Black Panther       $700,059,566
```

How can I automate the scraping of the subsequent urls until we reach the end of the data, so that the output is one long df that has been `rowbind()`ed together?

Comment: there's a `<div>` classed with `class="pagination"` at the bottom of every page with links to the next `n` pages. start with the first page, scrape the table and the pagination info and iterate until there's no more links. there are plenty of examples of that on SO (some very recent)

Comment: as an aside, while http://www.the-numbers.com/robots.txt does not implement a technical control for this path, folks with some shred of ethics should read https://www.the-numbers.com/research-analysis and at least donate (like $1.00 USD even)  if they're going to use the data.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am glad you pointed out that link to me, and I will contribute

Comment: FWIW I actually practice what I blather on abt. I made the OMDB API package — https://github.com/hrbrmstr/omdbapi — and can show the patreon monthly receipts for $1.00 USD even though I actually personally never use the API when I'm not teaching advanced R courses (and I haven't taught that in the past 3 semesters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked a few months shy of 3 years ago; however here is a solution.

First, it's always a good idea to determine whether scraping the website is allowed. In R, we can use the `robotstxt` package:

```
robotstxt::paths_allowed("https://www.the-numbers.com")
 www.the-numbers.com                      

[1] TRUE
```

Okay, we're good to go. Also, I'd like to reiterate what was pointed out by @hrbrmstr about donating (even the smallest amount) as a way to support what the people behind the website (or any other similar website) are doing.

The scraping function I define below makes use of the repeat/if construct in R (which is similar to a do-while loop in other programming languages). Also, since there is an unknown number of pages to scrape, the function has a `page_count` argument, which is `Inf` by default. Leaving it like that will scrape all pages from the website. However, if one would like to scrape, say, 10 pages, then they could set `page_count = 10`. Here is the function definition:

```
# Load packages ----

pacman::p_load(
  rvest,
  glue,
  stringr,
  dplyr,
  cli
)

# Custom function ----

scrape_data <- function(url, page_count = Inf){
  
  i <- 1
  data_list <- list()
  
  repeat {
    
    html <- read_html(url) 
    
    data_list[[i]] <- html %>%
      html_element(css = "table") %>%
      html_table()
    
    current_page <- html %>%
      html_element(css = "div.pagination > a.active") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      str_remove_all(pattern = "\\,")
    
    all_displayed_pages <- html %>%
      html_elements(css = "div.pagination > a") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      str_remove_all(pattern = "\\,") %>%
      str_extract(pattern = "\\d+\\-\\d+")
    
    all_pages_urls <- html %>%
      html_elements(css = "div.pagination > a") %>%
      html_attr(name = "href")
    
    url <- glue("https://www.the-numbers.com{all_pages_urls[which(current_page == all_displayed_pages)+1]}")
    cli_alert_success(glue("Scraped page: {i}"))
    
    i <- i + 1
    
    if(
      current_page == all_displayed_pages[length(all_displayed_pages)] |
      i - 1 == page_count
    ){
      break
    }
  }
  
  bind_rows(data_list)
  
}
```

Now let's use the function to scrape the first 5 pages of the table:

```
scrape_data(
  url = "https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/domestic/all-movies/cumulative/all-time",
  page_count = 5
)

√ Scraped page: 1
√ Scraped page: 2
√ Scraped page: 3
√ Scraped page: 4
√ Scraped page: 5
# A tibble: 500 x 7
    Rank  Year Movie                                Distributor `DomesticBox Of~ `InternationalB~ `WorldwideBox O~
   <int> <int> <chr>                                <chr>       <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
 1     1  2015 Star Wars Ep. VII: The Force Awakens Walt Disney $936,662,225     $1,127,953,592   $2,064,615,817  
 2     2  2019 Avengers: Endgame                    Walt Disney $858,373,000     $1,939,427,564   $2,797,800,564  
 3     3  2009 Avatar                               20th Cent…  $760,507,625     $2,085,391,916   $2,845,899,541  
 4     4  2018 Black Panther                        Walt Disney $700,059,566     $636,434,755     $1,336,494,321  
 5     5  2018 Avengers: Infinity War               Walt Disney $678,815,482     $1,365,725,041   $2,044,540,523  
 6     6  1997 Titanic                              Paramount…  $659,363,944     $1,548,622,601   $2,207,986,545  
 7     7  2015 Jurassic World                       Universal   $652,306,625     $1,017,673,342   $1,669,979,967  
 8     8  2012 The Avengers                         Walt Disney $623,357,910     $891,742,301     $1,515,100,211  
 9     9  2017 Star Wars Ep. VIII: The Last Jedi    Walt Disney $620,181,382     $711,453,759     $1,331,635,141  
10    10  2018 Incredibles 2                        Walt Disney $608,581,744     $634,223,615     $1,242,805,359  
# ... with 490 more rows
```

A possible improvement to the function is the addition of some time of inactivity with `Sys.sleep(3)` (for 3 seconds) in case the server kicks you out of the website for trying to hit it too many times too quickly.

Comment: Just curious how you stumbled onto this question: are you working on a project using this data? Thanks for a great answer

Comment: @JeremyK. You're very welcome. Glad I could help. No, not really. I am currently learning about how to scrape things that are not so obvious to scrape, so I was looking for examples on the internet to try my hands on. That's how I found your question.